# fire base sdk for php showing error for new Factory()

Tags: php, firebase, error-handling

### My code for `tester.php`

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
$factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount('./../../landoflearners-firebase-adminsdk-v70d3-d7e08e3f89.json');
$auth = $factory->createAuth();
```

### My directory structure

[image]

### error

**intelephense error**

```
Undefined type 'Kreait\Firebase\Factory'
```

[image]

#### package.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "kreait/firebase-php": "^5.20"
    }
}
```